# TFS2010 build with unit test

Tags: nunit-2.5

I am trying to convert a build system setup with TeamCity and Nant scripts to use TFS2010 (We bought the license and might just as well make use of it) After some work I get the web project to build and deploy to the web-server. We have a domain, API, test and web project in our solution.

How do I configure TFS to run the unit tests that we have written so far? I did configure the build to look for ***.UnitTest.dll in(VS2010) Edit build definition>Process>Automated Tests

Now the build fails with a message that says:"Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.3.9345" Am I correct when I say that TFS is trying to run NUnit on the build server? I did install NUnit-2.5.3.9345 on that TFS2010 build server and still nothing?

Thank you

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build facility in **TFS uses [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) as test runner**, with which it's tightly integrated.

If you want to run your unit tests with NUnit as part of your build, take a look at the [NUnit for Team Build project on CodePlex](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/).

The project started out for TFS 2008, however [support for TFS 2010 has been added](http://www.heikura.info/blog/publish-nunit-test-results-as-part-of-team-build-in-team-foundation-server-2010) in [version 2.0](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/releases/view/45765). Note that this feature is still in early stages of development, so [your mileage may vary](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/discussions/235330?ProjectName=nunit4teambuild).

Comment: I was hoping for another answer but it seems like this is the best for what we have, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game, because I've had to deal with this issue recently. I found this article helpful for me in this. It didn't work right off the bat, but I found if I added it into my buildscript via the controls in a similar manner/pattern, it would work.

My only problem now has been getting it to actually error (right now it warns) even when flagging them to cause the build to error

Link: http://blog.gfader.com/2011/06/running-nunit-tests-in-tfs-2010.html